# How can I use Composer to put scripts from my private repo in ~/.composer/vendor

Tags: bash, composer-php

I like how a few tools including `drush/drush` and `psy/psysh` can be installed with `composer global require ...` so that they have executables symlinked into `~/.composer/vendor/bin`.

While I still needed to add `~/.composer/vendor/bin` to my $PATH, after that the updates are simple: `composer global update`.

So, my question, I have a private repository, and I'd like to have this installed globally in the same way as drush and psysh, with the following command:

```
composer global require MY/PACKAGE
```

Assuming that I have control over the contents of the repository, and can put a composer.json or packages.json in it, what is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make the repository available to Composer by running:

```
composer config -g repositories.<name> <type> <url>
```

- Substitute `<name>` with a unique name to identify your repository (e.g. `myrepo`).
- Substitute `<type>` with the type of repository (most likely `vcs`, see [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)).
- Substitute `<url>` with the url to your repository (private server, bitbucket, github, etc.).

You can read more on this in the [documentation here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#modifying-repositories).

Then you can simply run:

```
composer global require your/package
```

Comment: Excellent, I sensed I was close... because I had no tags on my repo, I needed to do this:

    composer global require your/package:dev-master

And to get my ./testing.php script in ./composer/vendor/bin, I needed to add this into my composer.json in the repo:

    "bin": [
        "testing.php"
    ]

Comment: Should the first line be `composer global config -g repositories.<name> <type> <url>`?

Comment: i want to mark this as the best answer but it doesn't fully answer the question. I'm not sure what stackoverflow good manners are here.

Comment: Well, the `bin` configuration has little to do with the question, and more with how to setup libraries with binaries using Composer in general.

The version constraint (`dev-master` in your case) really depends on whether or not you have tags, or/and if not, what branch you want to use.

You don't have to add `global` to the first line, since that is what the `-g` argument is for.